# aws multipart upload change token solution?

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-web-services

I was trying to implement a multipart upload by using S3UploadPartRequest class. However I was wondering how to deal the following situation:

During the multipart uploading , I change the token for some reason like ExpiredToken. And here is my question: should I start over the uploading or the part I uploaded still working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the part I already uploaded still working, I just need to upload rest of them.